# Animating ease and timing for javascript behavior: smooth;

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner javascript. I am doing this code:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth',
        });
    });
});
```

For smooth scrolling links on home page. It works very well, but I would like to animate the ease function with either ease-in-out or cubic-bezier or something.  I would also like to modifying the timing function as well, so it takes for example 1000ms or 5000ms to scroll.
I have tried the doing of `easing: ease-in-out;` as I have seen this before on Stack Overflow. but it did not work.

Help would be much appreciated.